# Simplest way to render a Cartesian grid and points with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, render, cartesian

So I've been messing with Ruby trying to make a sort of chicken simulator. I have all these instances of class `Chicken` with `@x` and `@y` variables which represent their position. They have methods like `step(direction,steps)`, `distance_from(object)`, `take_shortest_path_to(object)`, etc.

There is a class `Nest` which places instances of itself on the grid and generates a group of `Chickens`, setting their starting positions to the `Nest`'s `@x` and `@y` values.

I plan to give the `Chicken`s the desire to go out into the "world", maybe in search of grain, with which they'll return to the `Nest` to stockpile. That actually sounds like SimAnt with chickens. Point is, I feel like a visual interface, even a very, very crude one, would be incredibly helpful at this point.*

But I'm not sure of the simplest way to do that. I feel like there's a *lot* more work I could do just on the logic before I really worry about how I'm going to actually render everything to the screen (if I even do; I'm really just doing this to learn the general vibe of OOP).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the chickens. But some code or indication of what you have tried would really help you get an answer. For game-like graphics you could check `gosu`, but warning that comes with a steep learning curve.

Comment: I'm really just trying for sub-Atari level graphics. Gems mystify me at this point, but I thought there might be a way to render very crude graphics with pure Ruby.

Comment: How much detail do you need? Would a single character per game character suffice? For example, `.` representing an open cell, `C` for chicken, `N` for nest, etc.

Comment: @user2493615: Ruby doesn't have graphics support built in, you will need a library of some kind if you want graphics. This is true of nearly all general-purpose languages.

Comment: Neil: Can you suggest a very lightweight and easy-to-use Ruby graphics library?

sawa: That would suffice for much of my needs. Can you suggest a tutorial, etc. that would help me achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

[Shoes](http://shoesrb.com) seems to be a pretty popular (and easy to learn) GUI framework.

A sample oval in a (apart from the oval) empty window would look like that:

```
Shoes.app {
  oval(left:   10,
       top:    10,
       radius: 40)
}
```

[image]

You could then draw your nest with an oval (your chicken with images, etc.)

Inserting images is simple too:

```
Shoes.app {
  image "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5e/Chicken_suit1.jpg"
}
```

Have a look at [their tutorials](http://shoesrb.com/tutorials.html) for details.

Comment: Could an actual game be made with Shoes? It seems to be geared toward Powerpoint-style presentations and such.

Comment: Technically the answer is yes - shoes relies on ruby, ruby is [turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_complete) ;) Probably your question is "How much effort is needed to implement a game with shoes?" The answer is: It depends (do you want fancy 3D graphics, or simple ovals bouncing around in a grey window?).